# Filtering IEnumerable with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of players, and I would like to only take out valid ones and put them in another `IEnumerable`.

This is how I do it:

```
private IEnumerable<Objects.Player> GetTargets() {
    var validTarget = Smurf.Objects.Players.Where(p => p.IsAlive && !p.IsDormant && p.Id != Smurf.LocalPlayer.Id);
    //Only gets the targets that is seen by me the localplayer.
    if (_aimSpotted)
        validTarget = validTarget.Where(p => p.SeenBy(Smurf.LocalPlayer));
    if (_aimEnemies)
        validTarget = validTarget.Where(p => !p.IsFriendly);
    if (_aimAllies)
        validTarget = validTarget.Where(p => p.IsFriendly);

    return validTarget;
}
```

And this is how I use that method:

```
                IEnumerable<Player> validTarget = GetTargets();
```

However, the issues is that `validTarget` will still contain a target with the ID that is the same to my `LocalPlayer`.

[image]

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. It looks like it should be fine.

Comment: your linq query seems to be correct...if you are still see the target with local player id then you should evaluate the data condition..Check if Smurf.LocalPlayer.Id is same as ID of local player

Comment: @JonSkeet This is the best I could do I believe http://puu.sh/mz5r6/aa491339ac.png

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson, He meant a complete post code of the problem, not a picture of the problem. Make a very small code sample and edit your post.

Comment: @OrelEraki I'm afraid that will be a bit tricky with just a small sample as I read memory from a game.

Comment: You do in your real app, yes. But we don't need the problem to be shown with your actual app code - we just need a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. Write a program that *just* does that, with nothing else. Use hardcoded data, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at `validTarget.source`, which is the collection that you originally passed to `Where()`.

If you look at the results (the last item in the expanded object), you'll see the filtered items.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into a problem related to deferred execution. When you return the LINQ statement, it hasn't actually executed yet; it executes when you actually enumerate the enumerable. Smurf.LocalPlayer.Id isn't actually resolved until that happens. You can force this to use an explicit value by setting Smurf.LocalPlayer.Id to a local variable before including in your where clause -or- force execution before the method returns (e.g. using ToArray()). 
Option #1 is usually preferable. 
Example: 
    var localPlayerId = Smurf.LocalPlayer.Id
    var validTarget = Smurf.Objects.Players.Where(p => p.IsAlive && !p.IsDormant && p.Id != localPlayerId);